# Linear Regression on Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

We have a situation where we have to run linear regression on millions of small datasets and store the weights and intercept for each of these datasets. I wrote the below scala code to do so, wherein I fed each of these datasets as a row in an RDD and then I try to run the regression on each(data is the RDD which has (label,features) stored in it in each row, in this case we have one feature per label):

```
val x = data.flatMap { line => line.split(' ')}.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(',')
  val parsedData1 = LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
  val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(sc.parallelize(List(parsedData1)),100)//using parallelize to convert data to type RDD
  (model.intercept,model.weights)
}
```

The problem here is that, **LinearRegressionWithSGD** expects an RDD for input, and nested RDDs are not supported in Spark. I chose this approach as all these datasets can be run independent of each other and hence I wanted to distribute them (Hence, ruled out looping).
Can you please suggest if I can use other types (Arrays, Lists etc) to input as a dataset to **LinearRegressionWithSGD** or even a better approach which will still distribute such computations in Spark?

Comment: Do you mean each small dataset can be handled in one machine? If so, you can use some linear regression library to do the train work in a map function. `LinearRegressionWithSGD` is used to train a big dataset.

Comment: Thanks. that's what I thought. And to answer your question, each dataset is indeed very small (maybe couple of hundred kbs). I will use an independent library to perform regression here.

Answer (score 0):

```
val modelList = for {item <- dataSet} yield {
    val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(context, item).cache()
    val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(data)
    model
}
```

Maybe you can separate your input data into several files and store in HDFS.
Use the directory of those files as input, you can get a list of models.